# transpose csv based on one column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, transpose

I saw a lot of examples transposing the data but not something similar. I am trying to transpose my csv data which looks like--

```
Region,1989,1900,2000
new york,3,4,5
atlanta,7,9,0
chicago,8,9,10
```

to

```
Region,Year,value
new york,1989,3
new york,1900,4
new york,2000,5
atlanta,1989,7
atlanta,1900,9
atlanta,2000,0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert from wide data format to long data format. This can be done using `melt` function. If you have some columns that needs to be eliminated, you can slice the dataframe to the columns of interest.

**Code:**

```
#creating df
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Region':['new york', 'atlanta', 'chicago'], '1989': [3,7,8], '1900': [4,9,9], '2000': [5,0,10]})

#converting to long format
long_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Region'], value_vars=['1989', '1900', '2000'], var_name='year', value_name = 'value')
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: In my opinion `value_vars=['1989', '1900', '2000']` should be omit

Comment: I just wanted to show that we can select the columns we want.

Comment: yes, I understand, but if there is more columns and need melt by all columns without `Region`